# Is there a simpler way to rebase commits into a (locally) merged branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-rebase

Assume I have the history – all local, nothing shared yet –

```
A ── B ── C ── D ────── E ── F ── G
      ╲        └topic0 ╱          ├local-master
       Γ ── Δ ─────── Ξ           └HEAD
                      └topic1
```

where

- `topic0` is a feature that's basically finished, but I hadn't properly debugged it when I merged it into `local-master`
- `topic1` is experimental/hackish, something I needed right now but isn't at all ready for pushing yet
- `G` is a bugfix that's needed  to get the feature of `topic0` working properly

What I want to do soon is push `topic0`, but together with the bugfix commit `G`. I.e., I want the history

```
A ── B ── C ── D ── G'────── E'── F'
      ╲             └topic0 ╱     └local-master
       Γ ── Δ ──────────── Ξ
                           └topic1
```

If it weren't for `topic1`, this would be very easy:

```
$ git rebase -i topic0
        # move G up so it comes after D
$ git checkout topic0
$ git merge G'
```

But this doesn't work here because `E` has more than just `D` as its ancestor, so instead I need

```
$ git checkout topic0
$ git cherry-pick G
$ git checkout -b tmp/topic0plus1
$ git merge topic1
$ git checkout local-master
$ git rebase tmp/topic0plus1
$ git branch -d tmp/topic0plus1
```

Which is much more fiddly.

Is there a simpler way of accomplishing the same rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simpler way of accomplishing the same rewrite?

No.  There are *other* ways, but not *simpler* ones.  A rewrite through a merge is not very well supported[1].  You could decide whether you prefer `cherry-pick` or `rebase` for rewriting `G`, but for a single commit it makes little difference.  Other similar variations are possible.

Re-creating the merge is the most dangerous step, where you need to know about how the merge was created (at least as far as, did it use the default merge strategy and options; were changes manually added to it; were there conflicts and how were they resolved).

Where you might make the most gains going forward would be to have a more structured approach to branching and merging.  It may or may not be easy to do with your workflow, but having a mainline and rules for when you merge into it can go a long way.  (For example, when you wanted to combine your experimental code with the mainline, possibly you could've merged `master` into `topic1` instead of the other way around, so that your mainline wouldn't be affected by the code while it's still experimental.)

---

[1] I keep debating whether that phrasing is fair; it's not an easy thing *to* support "well".  But the point is, it's not something that's made easy from a user perspective.